# Repeating last element on linked list

Tags: java, list, linked-list

I have a linkNode(named List) that has the following values

> x y z 1 2 3

And I want it to look like this:

> x y z 1 2 3 3

I wrote the following:

```
ListNode front=list;
ListNode back = list;
while (front != null)
{
    back = front;
    front = list.getNext();
}

ListNode x = new ListNode (front.getValue(),back.getNext());
back.getNext().setNext(x);
```

Why is this not working? I do not really get an error, when I run the code it prints out the previous methods that I have and this one is just blank

Method that prints:

```
public static void print(ListNode list)
{
    String p="";
    while(list!=null)
    {
        p+=list.getValue()+" ";
        list=list.getNext();
    }

    System.out.println(p);
}
```

Method that adds nodes:

```
ListNode z = new ListNode("x",
                 new ListNode("y",
                     new ListNode("z",
                         new ListNode("1",
                             new ListNode("2",
                                 new ListNode("3",,null)))));
```

Comment: Please provide full code. Method which is printing linked list and code which is adding elements.

Comment: So you just want to repeat the last element while printing. Because currently it's printing all node values. You can simply check whether next node is null or not to duplicate the last element in print.

Comment: I can do that but I am trying to learn how to add elements @TAsk

Answer (score 1):

OK, there's a number of issues here; in your loop you do:

```
front = list.getNext();
```

That's not going to go anywhere, just repeating getting the head of the list. Try:

```
front = front.getNext();
```

Next you do:

```
ListNode x = new ListNode (front.getValue(),back.getNext());
back.getNext().setNext(x);
```

If you fix the loop above, `front` at this point is `null`, so this becomes:

```
ListNode x = new ListNode (null.getValue(), null);
null.setNext(x);
```

This is going to crash badly, so I think you want:

```
ListNode x = new ListNode(back.getValue(),back.getNext());
back.setNext(x);
```

However, without seeing the code of `setNext()`, etc, I'm not too sure if this is correct.

Answer (score 0):

This is full solution.

The structure of node is:

```
class ListNode{
    char ch;
    ListNode next;

    ListNode(char ch,ListNode next){
        this.ch=ch;
        this.next=next;
    }
}
```

Then the method that adds the last character at the end is:

```
private ListNode repeatLastChar(ListNode list) {
    ListNode front=list;
    ListNode back = list;
    while (front != null)
    {
        back = front;
        front = front.next;
    }
    ListNode x = new ListNode (back.ch,null);
    back.next=x;
    return list;
}
```